# How to apply flex behaviors in a row via sass?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sass, bootstrap-4

For example I have this HTML:

```html
    <div class="header__container">
      <div class="header__info-row">
        <section class="social__col">
        </section>
        <section class="contact__col">
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>
```

With sass I specify rows and col like this:

```css
    .header__container {
      @include make-container();
    }

    .header__info-row {
      @include make-row();
    }

    .header__navigation-row {
      @include make-row();
    }

    .social__col {
      @include make-col-ready();

      @include media-breakpoint-up(xs) {
        @include make-col(6);
      }
    }

    .contact__col {
      @include make-col-ready();

      @include media-breakpoint-up(xs) {
        @include make-col(6);
      }
    }
```

Is there any way to specify inside sass flex-behaviors like d-flex, justify-content, align-content etc?

Comment: What's preventing you from using `display: flex;` and normal CSS rules?

Answer (score 0):

As far as you can see at Bootstrap's documentation, besides sass mixins, they also provide classes in order to control css behavior of grid elements. For example

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
<div class="row justify-content-end">
<div class="col align-self-start">
```

So I'm pretty sure if you fiddle with those classes, you will get the behavior you want.

If you want a custom solution, write your own sass mixin and include it after Bootstrap's mixin in order to override defaults they provide.